# How to match two 2d list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I'm having trouble finding find a match in any columns in df1 that match any columns in df2 and return the matching values and values. For example,

```
df1 = [[2,4,6,8,9,10],[10,13,15,17,26,44],[27,28,34,37,40]]

df2 = [[1,2,4,5,6,8],[5,6,20,22,23,34],[8,12,13,34,45,46],[9,10,14,29,32,33],[1,22,13,23,33,35],[1,6,7,8,9,10],[0,2,3,5,6,8]]
```

I would like my results to be like this below

```
 result = [[1,2,2,4,5,6,6,8,8,9,10],
[2,4,5,6,6,8,9,10,20,22,23,34],
[2,4,6,8,8,9,10,12,13,34,45,46]
[2,4,6,8,9,9,10,10,14,29,32,33]
[1,2,4,6,6,7,8,8,9.10,10]
[0,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,8,8,9,10]],

[[8,10,12,13,13,15,17,26,34,44,45,46],
[9,10,10,13,14,15,17,26,29,32,33,44],
[1,6,7,8,9,10,10,13,15,17,26,44]],

[[5,6,20,22,23,,27,28,34,34,37,40]
[8,12,13,27,28,34,37,40,45,46]]
```

Comment: How exactly do you get the resulting list? I see no pattern in how the two dataframes should be matched.

Comment: for example df1[0] has 2,4,6,8 and df2[0] has 2,4,6,8 etc

Comment: So then why is 1 in the resulting list when it's only in the second dataframe? Please provide a more clear and preferably shorter example illustrating what you want to have happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sets to establish if there is match and concatenate/sort the subllists to the output lists.

I couldn't get exactly your expected result, but close (perhaps `[1, 10, 13, 13, 15, 17, 22, 23, 26, 33, 35, 44]` on the second groups was missing from your example):

```
result = [ [sorted(c1+c2) for c2 in df2 if set(c1)&set(c2)] for c1 in df1 ]

for group in result:
    print(*group,sep="\n")
    print()

[1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 10, 20, 22, 23, 34]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 34, 45, 46]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 14, 29, 32, 33]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10]
[0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10]

[8, 10, 12, 13, 13, 15, 17, 26, 34, 44, 45, 46]
[9, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 17, 26, 29, 32, 33, 44]
[1, 10, 13, 13, 15, 17, 22, 23, 26, 33, 35, 44] # <-- extra
[1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 13, 15, 17, 26, 44]

[5, 6, 20, 22, 23, 27, 28, 34, 34, 37, 37, 40]
[8, 12, 13, 27, 28, 34, 34, 37, 37, 40, 45, 46]
```

*Note that using sets assumes that you don't have duplicate values in the sublists. If you do, then you would need to use the `Counter` class from collections instead of `set`.*

Comment: Kind of close . i updated my and results. Maybe u can help me.

Comment: Updated my answer, still have an extra list in my results though.